# Show Error Message if Nothing is selected from any of the Drop Down List's

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, web

[image]

I have a lot of drop down lists in this page, I have been trying to add a validator to the page so that it shows an error message when clicked Proceed button if nothing is selected from any one of the drop down lists

**This is Booking.aspx.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

public partial class Booking : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {




    }

    }
```

**This is Booking.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Booking.aspx.cs" Inherits="Booking" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .auto-style1 {
            width: 100%;
        }
        .auto-style2 {
            width: 320px;
            text-align: right;
        }
        .auto-style3 {
            text-align: right;
            width: 434px;
        }
        .auto-style4 {
            width: 434px;
        }
        .auto-style5 {
            text-align: center;
            width: 424px;
        }
        .auto-style6 {
            width: 300px;
            height: 288px;
        }
        .auto-style7 {
            text-align: center;
            background-color: #D3C8C2;
        }
        .auto-style8 {
            width: 320px;
            text-align: right;
            height: 74px;
        }
        .auto-style9 {
            text-align: right;
            width: 434px;
            height: 74px;
        }
        .auto-style10 {
            height: 74px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div class="auto-style7">

        <div class="auto-style7">
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <br />
            <br />
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <img alt="" class="auto-style6" src="Images/GC.jpg" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/Default.aspx">Home</asp:HyperLink>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <br />
        </div>
        <table class="auto-style1">
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style8">
                    <br />
                </td>
                <td class="auto-style9">
                    <h1 class="auto-style5">Choose a type of ticket:<br />
                    </h1>
                </td>
                <td class="auto-style10"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style2">Gold Class</td>
                <td class="auto-style3">
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True">
                        <asp:ListItem>0</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>1</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>2</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>3</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>4</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>5</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>6</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>7</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Enabled="False">8</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>9</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>10</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>11</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>12</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>13</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>14</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>15</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>16</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>17</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>18</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>19</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>20</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style2">Silver Class</td>
                <td class="auto-style3">
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList3" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True">
                        <asp:ListItem>0</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>1</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>2</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>3</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>4</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>5</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>6</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>7</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>8</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>9</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>10</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>11</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>12</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>13</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>14</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>15</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>16</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>17</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>18</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>19</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>20</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style2">Standard</td>
                <td class="auto-style3">
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList4" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True">
                        <asp:ListItem>0</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>1</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>2</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>3</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>4</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>5</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>6</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>7</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>8</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>9</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>10</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>11</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>12</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>13</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>14</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>15</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>16</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>17</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>18</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>19</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>20</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>21</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>22</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>23</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>24</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>25</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>26</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>27</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>28</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>29</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>30</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>31</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>32</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>33</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>34</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>45</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>36</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>37</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>38</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>39</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>40</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </td>
                <td>
                    &nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style2">Student</td>
                <td class="auto-style3">
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList5" runat="server">
                        <asp:ListItem Value="0">0</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>1</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>2</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>3</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>4</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>5</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>6</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>7</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>8</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>9</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>10</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>11</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>12</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>13</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>14</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>15</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>16</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>17</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>18</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>19</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>20</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>21</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>22</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>23</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>24</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>25</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>26</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>27</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>28</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>29</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>30</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>31</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>32</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>33</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>34</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>35</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>36</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>37</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>38</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>39</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>40</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style2">Child</td>
                <td class="auto-style3">
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList6" runat="server">
                        <asp:ListItem>0</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>1</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>2</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>3</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>4</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>5</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>6</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>7</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>8</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>9</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>10</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>11</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>12</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>13</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>14</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>15</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>16</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>17</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>18</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>19</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>20</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>21</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>22</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>23</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>24</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>25</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>26</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>27</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>28</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>29</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>30</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>31</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>32</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>33</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>34</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>35</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>36</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>37</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>38</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>39</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>40</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style2">Senior</td>
                <td class="auto-style3">
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList7" runat="server">
                        <asp:ListItem>0</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>1</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>2</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>3</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>4</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>5</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>6</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>7</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>8</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>9</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>10</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>11</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>12</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>13</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>14</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>15</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>16</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>17</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>18</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>19</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>20</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>21</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>22</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>23</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>24</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>25</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>26</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>27</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>28</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>29</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>30</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>31</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>32</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>33</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>34</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>35</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>36</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>37</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>38</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>39</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>40</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style2">&nbsp;</td>
                <td class="auto-style4">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <br />
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" style="text-align: right" Text="Proceed" />
                    <br />
                </td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <br />

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you can check it with a or condition

Comment: I'm new to asp.net, can you please help me with the code @sachu. I'd really appreciate that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put a if condition to achieve the same

```
if( DropDownList2.Text == "0" && DropDownList3.Text== "0" &&
    DropDownList4.Text == "0" && DropDownList5.Text == "0"
    || DropDownList6.Text == "0" && DropDownList7.Text == "0")
{
    Response.Write("Please select the quantity of the ticket.");
}
```

Comment: I don't want the user to select all the drop down lists. A user can select one or more if he/she wants to but they must select at least one.

Comment: @Rajat modified my answer pls check

Comment: Thank you very much, it helped a lot.